# How to use enum values with Joi String validation

Tags: node.js, validation, express, joi

I am using the Joi validator for my HTTP requests. There I have a parameter called `type`. I need to make sure that the possible values for the parameter are either `ios` or `android`.

How can I do that?

```js
body: {
  device_key : joi.string().required(),
  type : joi.string().required()
}
```

Answer (score 150, accepted):

You can use `valid`.

```
const schema = Joi.object().keys({
  type: Joi.string().valid('ios', 'android'),
});

const myObj = { type: 'none' };
const result = Joi.validate(myObj, schema);
console.log(result);
```

This gives an error `ValidationError: child "type" fails because ["type" must be one of [ios, android]]`

Comment: Readers take note that `valid()` accepts many strings, *not* an array of strings.

Answer (score 48):

Maybe it will be useful for anyone who wants to check values based on existing enum/array of values.

```
const SomeEnumType = { TypeA: 'A', TypeB: 'B' };
```

Then just use this:

```
const schema = Joi.object().keys({
  type: Joi.string().valid(...Object.values(SomeEnumType)),
});

const myObj = { type: 'none' };
const result = Joi.validate(myObj, schema);
```

Comment: This also works for Arrays. Very useful when you have, for example, an array of roles that you might want to validate against. Thanks @max-podriezov, it helped me with my case scenario.

Comment: you don't need to spread the `Object.values()` since `valid()` takes an array. so remove the `...`

Comment: On the latest version of Joi, `.valid()` no longer takes an array argument, so we need to spread the array using `...`. See:
https://github.com/sideway/joi/issues/1449

Comment: I suggest you provide also enum syntax in your example code - I was convinced at first glance this is unprecise answer.

Comment: as @Kariem showed in its answer, this also works with an actual `enum`, i.e. `enum SomeEnumType { TypeA: 'A', ... }`

Comment: This is wrong. `Object.values(SomeEnumType)` here is `['A', 'B', 0, 1]`. It should be `Object.values(SomeEnumType).filter((l) => isNaN(Number(l)))` instead to only allow `A` and `B`

Answer (score 8):

For typescript, I think the most straightforward way is to just add the enum's values as valid values.

```js
enum DeviceType {
    iOS = 'ios',
    Android = 'android',
}

Joi.string()
  // .allow(null) // uncomment this line to allow 'null'
  .valid(... Object.values(DeviceType))
```

This is essentially what [jarora](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63598479) and [Sinapcs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70856946) suggested in previous answers without the separate function.

Comment: +1 for demonstrating an  actual `enum` and without an extra function. Sadly however this doesn't work for `const enum` :(

Answer (score 3):

I am late for this answer.
But following will helpful for others, who wants to use enum values with Joi String validation :

```
function validateBody(bodyPayload) {
    const schema = Joi.object({
        device_key : Joi.string().required(),
        type : Joi.string().valid('ios','android'),

    });
    return schema.validate(admin);
}

const bodyPayload = {device_key:"abc", type: "web"};
const result = validateBody(bodyPayload);
```

> reference : https://hapi.dev/module/joi/api/#anyallowvalues

Answer (score 3):

```
function getEnumValues<T extends string | number>(e: any): T[] {
    return typeof e === 'object' ? Object.values(e) : [];
}

Joi.string().valid(...getEnumValues(YOUR_ENUM));
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 1):

For typescript users,

```
getEnumValues<T extends string | number>(e: any): T[] {
        return typeof e === 'object' ? Object.keys(e).map(key => e[key]) : [];
}

Joi.string().valid(...getEnumValues(YOUR_ENUM));
```