# Validation for active and inactive status

Tags: node.js, joi

Actually am new to this technology so my question was in my schema there is a column status. The status should active or inactive so for this i have to add joi validation.I don't know how to do it so can anyone please tell me how to do it?

**Schema**

```
const USER_SCHEMA = {
    user_full_name: Joi.string().min(3).max(20).regex(/^[ A-Za-z0-9]+$/).required(),
    user_email: Joi.string().min(5).max(50).email().required(),
    user_status: 
};
```

Comment: here's your answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50156176/how-to-use-enum-values-with-joi-string-validation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can mention a list of data you want to compare in array form like below.

```
const USER_SCHEMA = {
    user_full_name: Joi.string().min(3).max(20).regex(/^[ A-Za-z0-9]+$/).required(),
    user_email: Joi.string().min(5).max(50).email().required(),
    user_status: Joi.valid(['active', 'inactive']).required()
};
```