# how to validate query parameters with custom function in hapi

Tags: node.js, hapi.js, joi

I have a query parameter `method` which can have 4 values like `sum`, `sub`, `div`, `mul`.
I want to validate if only above 4 values are passed in the query param or combination of above 4 values are passed with comma separated.

Correct cases:

1. method=sum
2. method=sum,mul

Incorrect cases:

1. method=per
2. method=sum,per

I have tried below to validate the single values:
`config = validate: { query: { method: joi.string().valid('sum','sub','mul','div')}}`

I want to validate combinations as well like `method=sum,div`

Comment: Disclaimer that I don't know joi but it's possible `query` needs to be a Joi object using `Joi.object().keys` as seen in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50156176/how-to-use-enum-values-with-joi-string-validation

Comment: Thanks for your support. I am able to validate one of the available values like `method=sum` but i want to validate `method=sum,mul` as success validation.

Comment: I'd suggest changing `method` to accept an array of strings rather than trying to validate a string that contains multiple valid/invalid options inside of it

Answer (score 0):

If the valid values for `method` are not that many, just hardcode them. For example:

```
joi.string().valid(
  'sum', 'sub', 'mul', 'div',
  'sum,div', 'sum,mul', 'sum,sub',
  // etc...
)
```

If there are too many combinations or you simply don't want to hardcode them, write a function that calculates them for you. Something like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20871714/3036129).